# ¿Cómo agregar la opción de subir/cargar/guardar imágenes a IMGUR desde una URL imagen?

Tags: javascript, api

Estoy implementando subir imágenes, fotos utilizando el sistema de `imgur`.

Hasta el momento he desarrollado la opción dropzone, que me permite arrastrar o hacer clic en Dropzone para subir/cargar imágenes y guardarlas en `imgur` y no en mi hosting local.

A través de mi código **upload.js.**

```
var feedback = function(res) {
    if (res.success === true) {
        var get_link = res.data.link.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
        document.querySelector('.status').classList.add('bg-success');
        document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML =
            'Image : ' + '<br><input class="image-url" value=\"' + get_link + '\"/>' + '<img class="img" alt="Imgur-Upload" src=\"' + get_link + '\"/>';
    }
};

new Imgur({
    clientid: '', //You can change this ClientID
    callback: feedback
});
```

Y desde una estructura simple de `HTML`.

```
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Imgur Upload API</h1>
        <p>Use JavaScript To Upload Image</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dropzone">
        <div class="info"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/imgur.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/upload.js"></script>
</body>
```

Obtengo mi `dropzone` que me permite subir/cargar las imágenes a hosting `imgur`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He agregado las siguientes líneas `fd.append('type', 'URL');` al código [imgur.js](https://jsfiddle.net/dkz37har/).

```
  var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', file);
    fd.append('type', 'URL');
```

Pero, ¿cómo se puede agregar la opción de ingresar una URL de imagen y subirla/cargarla guardar en imgur?

Quiero agregar las dos opciones en mi dropzone, subir imágenes localmente y usar una URL de imagen.

El mismo sistema de StackOverflow, que permite arrastrar inagen/ seleccionar imagen y la vez permite subir imágenes desde un URL imagen ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según la [API de Imgur](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139) el parámetro `image` puede ser "un archivo binario, datos en base64 o **una URL de una imagen**". Con esto en mente puedes simplemente enviar el URL que quieras al API.

Comment: Hola @JCAguilera pero como hago para subir esa imagen mediante una URL imagen, hasta el momento yo puedo enviar esas imágenes seleccionando las imágenes en mi ordenador, pero yo quiero saber qué implementación debo hacer para subir esa URL imagen a `imgur`

Comment: Sólo envía un URL, como: `http://imagenes.com/imagen.jpg`

Comment: pero es que si fuera tan fácil como lo dices en el comentario no hubiera preguntado, no me ayuda su respuesta.

Comment: No es tan complicado lo que quieres hacer, si lees la api, en el parámetro `image` acepta base64, archivo binario o una url, debes crear un input y asegurarte que cuando vaya a enviar los datos el nombre del input haga match con el parámetro `image`. No podrías enviar imagen y url a la vez, así que si usan el input asegúrate que no usen el input de imagen

Comment: Hola @GermanAlzate puedes mostrarme el ejemplo, yo ya me he matado leyendo todo los datos de imgur, y no entiendo nada :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He echado un vistazo a tu pregunta y a la librería de **imgur**.

Por un lado indicarte que esta librería esta **disponible en github**. Quizá debes contemplar la posibilidad de contribuir al proyecto, crear tu propia variante o ponerte en contacto con su autor para incluir esta nueva característica.

Por otro lado, y sin modificar la librería actual de un tercero, puedes utilizar este pequeño 'hack' para conseguir tu objetivo.

```
var imgur = new Imgur({
            clientid: '',
            callback: feedback
});

var d = new FormData;
d.append("image", "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/316/1*LUfpOf7teWvPdIPTBmYciA.png"),

imgur.post(imgur.endpoint, d, imgur.callback);
```

**Simplemente, se trata de utilizar el método POST de la librería de imgur utilizando como valor image cualquier url dada.**

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcionar en es siguiente código implementando un formulario de envió fuera del **dropzone** facilitado por la librería.

```js
var feedback = function(res) {
    if (res.success === true) {
        var get_link = res.data.link.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
        document.querySelector('.status').classList.add('bg-success');
        document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML =
            'Image : ' + '<br><input class="image-url" value=\"' + get_link + '\"/>' + '<img class="img" alt="Imgur-Upload" src=\"' + get_link + '\"/>';
    }
};

(function() {
  var imgur = new Imgur({
      clientid: 'cc86a8de0e7c459',
      callback: feedback
  });

function onSubmit(event, form) {
    if (event) { event.preventDefault(); }

   var d = new FormData;
   d.append("image", this.image.value);

    //debugger;
   imgur.post(imgur.endpoint, d, imgur.callback);
}

var form = document.getElementById('linkform');
form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit, false);
form.submit = onSubmit;
  
})();
```

```css
#linkform > * {width: 100%; margin: 2px}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pinceladasdaweb/imgur/3ee965f9/src/imgur.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pinceladasdaweb/imgur/3ee965f9/src/imgur.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Imgur Upload API</h1>
        <p>es.stackoverflow.com @dperezv.com</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form id="linkform">
          <input type="text" name="image" value="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/316/1*LUfpOf7teWvPdIPTBmYciA.png" />
          <button type="submit">Subir a imgur</button>
      </form><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="dropzone">
        <div class="info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta +1, saludos.